# Objective-C Using custom XiB in another XiB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, xib

I've really spent my hours for finding any approach about this problem.

I have;

**CustomView.h** that extends from `UIView` and is also IB_DESIGNABLE
  **CustomView.m** for implementation of this view with override methods `init`, `initWithCoder` and `initWithFrame`
 **CustomView.xib** that bound to CustomView class with all properties
And, I have :

> - CustomTableViewCell.h that extends from UITableViewCell
> - CustomTableViewCell.m that implementation of this cell
> - CustomTableViewCell.xib that bound to CustomTableViewCell class with all properties&outlets.

CustomTableViewCell.xib includes CustomView...

There is no any error, but the area of CustomView remains blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For view you need to do some work around.

Create a property and link your view in the `XIB` to it;

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *xibView;`

Then have something like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self commonInit];
}

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit{
    //this will work if the view has the same name as the XIB
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
    self.xibView.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:self.xibView];
    self.xibView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

}
```

Basically you have to load the `XIB` manually and add it to your custom view.